# Oracle function to PostgreSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql, plsql, psql

I'm try to convert my Oracle function which contains `SUBSTR()` to PostgreSQL. Is there an equivalent function in PSQL? Thanks.

I manage to find a Oracle Instr() conversion to [PostgreSQL](http://www.dbaref.com/postgresql-database/instrfunctioninpostgresql).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a code from Postgres documentation mentioned by michel-sim. Other possibility is Orafce extension - https://github.com/orafce/orafce or http://postgres.cz/wiki/Oracle_functionality_%28en%29 that is available for RedHat or Debian as binary package too.

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking the tutorial how to install orafce. I bit tricky for not Perl user myself.

Comment: As mention in Orafce `Install.orafunc` - ..install Orafce functions in the database, either run the orafce.sql script 
using the pgAdmin SQL tool..I tried running the `orafce--3.0.sql`, it give me error `ERROR:  could not access file "MODULE_PATHNAME": No such file or directory`. What do you mean by module path?

Comment: Here's my question on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523731/installing-orafce-sql-3-0-in-windows-7)

Comment: @Charlesliam - please, try CREATE EXTENSION orafce;

Comment: I did try but I have a problem runnnig the `CREATE EXTENSION orafce`. Here's my [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523731/installing-orafce-sql-3-0-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 2):

There's [`substring`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html), but you'd have to modify the invocations -- instead of `substr(x, i, j)` you need `substring(x from i to j)`

Comment: It's trivial to write a wrapper SQL function around that, of course, giving you the `substr` you're used to ... but it's better to use orafce as Pavel suggested.

Comment: Indeed, I might try orafce myself for migrating some databases at work