# Orafce install in postgresql 9.5

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.5, orafce

I am new to programmer world so i want to learn so many things, and about what i want to ask, can i install orafce in postgresql? I mean all the tutorial always show use BigSql but iam using from enterprise DB. I am already try take orafce.dll from bigsql but it can't read because not specified procedure.

`ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/lib/orafce.dll": The specified procedure could not be found.`

and i already try from other source but still got some error

```
ERROR:  could not find function "plvlex_tokens" in file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/lib/orafce.dll"
```

Comment: did you `create extension orafce`?.. please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/21926348/5315974

Comment: Yes i am `create extension orafce` Thanks for your information.. Really helpful @VaoTsun

Comment: You'll probably have to get an `orafce.dll` that is specifically built for EnterpriseDB's binary distribution. From where did you get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in Orafce windows build. Should be fixed by last build.

Comment: Could you share the link?

Comment: @DwiRahmanIsmail http://okbob.blogspot.cz/2017/12/bugfix-of-precompiled-dll-of-orafce-362.html